# ProxyPass entire domain to Tomcat, including root

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, reverse-proxy, rewrite

I have configured my `VirtualHost` **example.com** to proxy all requests to a Tomcat server

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8088/app
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8088/app
```

This works fine for URLs like **example.com/page**, but for **example.com** and **example.com/** I get this redirection response, which obviously leads to nothing.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 21:13:37 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1             <-- the redirect comes from tomcat
Location: http://example.com/app/     <-- nonsense
...
```

What can I do to fix it? Preferably in the Apache config.

I'm using Apache 2 and Tomcat 7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why, but this is the fix

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8088/app/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8088/app/
```

(Added slashes to the end)

Comment: Slashes should always match.  From the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass): `If the first argument ends with a trailing /, the second argument should also end with a trailing / and vice versa. Otherwise the resulting requests to the backend may miss some needed slashes and do not deliver the expected results.`